# supported graphics card

Tags: xorg

My ubuntu-14.04 boot up with intel driver, as the underlying graphics chipset is supported by this driver.

Is there any way that can list out the supported chipset by given chipset driver ?

e.g. "intel_drv.so" supports

```
intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
     i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
     915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
     Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
     GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
     (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
     (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
     (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
```